# Gemspec resolve dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I wanted to create a gem with some dependencies. I followed a tutorial, [here](https://github.com/moredip/didactic_clock) is the full code.

I have

```
s.add_dependency "sinatra"
```

In the gemspec. I build the gem. When I tried to install it with

```
gem install --local gemname.gem
```

I got

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sinatra' (>= 0) in any repository

I instead expected that `gem install` will first install *sinatra* and then proceed with my gem.

How can I make it install any dependencies prior to my gem? I tried to:

- add `gem 'sinatra'` to the gemfile
- use `add_runtime_dependency` instead of `add_dependency`
- `require 'rubygems'` on top of my gemspec file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```
gem install gemname.gem # NO --local switch
```

---

When given, `--local` restricts *all* the actions to local domain, as clearly written in `gem help install` output:

> Local/Remote Options:
>
> ```
> -l, --local                      Restrict operations to the LOCAL domain
> ```

That said, the above will succeed if and only `sinatra` is *already available in local*.

Comment: I thought `--local` was used to specify the path to the local file. Thank you, you have no idea how much time I was stuck on this! I love you!